# Repeating background across multiple pages CSS for markdown PDF

Tags: css, markdown

For some development project, we are documenting background in Markdown in combination with a CSS stylesheet when exporting to PDF. With this we want to also put a watermark on this PDF file. However, when adding this watermark to the stylesheet, it only shows up on the first page of the PDF.

The code I am using within the stylesheet is as follows:

```
body {
  font-family: Calibri;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  background-image: url("model_documentation/images_runbook/watermark.png");
  background-image: center;
  background-size: 90%;
  background-repeat: space;
  padding: 30px;
  color: #333;
  counter-reset: h1
}
```

Thereby using the Markdown-PDF VSCode plugin for exporting to PDF.